# Add and Remove Class to Element with JavaScript on mouseEnter

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'd like to be able to add and remove classes based on the users mouse moving over certain areas. Below is the navigation code as generate by WordPress:

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" data-small-nav-title="Navigation">
    <ul id="menu-new-blog-main-2" class="nav-bar clearfix">
    <li id="menu-item-10168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10168"><a href="http://www.proformablog.com/about-proforma/">About Proforma</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10169"><a href="http://www.proforma.com">Proforma.com</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10170" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10170"><a href="http://proforma.com/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>               
    </nav>
```

I've come up with the following JavaScript that targets the `<li>` in order to change the class of the link within the `<li>`:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#site-navigation li').mouseenter(function(){   

    $(this).find('li.menu-item a').addClass('animated, bounceIn');
    //$(this).find('.span').addClass('fadeInUp');

    });


    $('#site-navigation li'').mouseleave(function(){    

    $('#site-navigation li'').find('li.menu-item a').removeClass('animated, bounceIn');
    //$('#site-navigation li').find('.span').removeClass('animated, fadeInUp');

    });
  });   
  </script>
```

I've checked the Console and it looks like the event isn't even firing for the code to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Also, have you enqueued your own version of jQuery, or are you using the WordPress default? Regardless, you can achieve all of this without JavaScript, using CSS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/o5fwjj4o/1/).

Here is the snippet. (I have added `alert` on `enter` and `leave` events for testing).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#site-navigation li').mouseenter(function() {
    alert("Enter " + $(this).text());

    $(this).find('li.menu-item a').addClass('animated, bounceIn');
    //$(this).find('.span').addClass('fadeInUp');

  });


  $('#site-navigation li').mouseleave(function() {

    alert("Leave " + $(this).text());

    $('#site-navigation li').find('li.menu-item a').removeClass('animated bounceIn');
    //$('#site - navigation li ').find('.span ').removeClass('animated, fadeInUp ');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" data-small-nav-title="Navigation">
  <ul id="menu-new-blog-main-2" class="nav-bar clearfix">
    <li id="menu-item-10168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10168"><a href="http://www.proformablog.com/about-proforma/">About Proforma</a>

    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-10169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10169"><a href="http://www.proforma.com">Proforma.com</a>

    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-10170" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10170"><a href="http://proforma.com/contact.html">Contact Us</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding/removing classes with jQuery, they should be space separated, not comma separated. So:

```
$(this).find('li.menu-item a').addClass('animated bounceIn');
```

Also, you shouldn't nest your `mouseleave` inside your `mouseenter` functions. Also, you should use `$.on` instead.

Also, within your event handlers, you aren't accessing your elements correctly. `$(this)` refers to the element that has been entered or left. Since you've set the mouseenter handler on the `<li>` elements, `$(this).find('li.menu-item a')` finds nothing.

Try this:

```
// It's often best practice to cache jQuery objects
// so you're not looking up the elements multiple times.
var $listItems = $('#site-navigation li');

$listItems.on('mouseenter', function(){   
  $(this).find('a').addClass('animated bounceIn');
});

$listItems.on('mouseleave', function(){   
  $(this).find('a').removeClass('animated bounceIn');
});
```

All of this said, if you're simply trying to have an animation on hover, you can achieve that in CSS only with a single class on your `<a>` elements. The jQuery might be overkill, here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still isn't firing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#site-navigation li'')
```

should be either

```
$('#site-navigation li')
```

or

```
$("#site-navigation li")
```

(You have wrong quote marks)

and prevent using selector's repetition, do it like this:

```
var $el = $('#site-navigation li')

$el.mouseenter(function(){   
     $(this).find('li.menu-item a').addClass('animated bounceIn');
     $(this).find('.span').addClass('fadeInUp');
});

$el.mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).find('li.menu-item a').removeClass('animated bounceIn');
}
```

For further reading: http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/

Good Luck